# Page size after pdfcrop doesn't match my calculations?

Tags: pdf

I'm running:

```
$ pdfcrop --margins '-36 -59 -49 -35'  tmp.pdf tmpo3.pdf
```

But the  page sizes before and after don't match with my calculation. My calculation shows that the page sizes in points after cropping should be 612-36-49 = 527 by 792-59-35 = 698 pts. But `pdfinfo` says it is 471 x 670 pts.  I think  `pdfcrop` removes more margins than specified. Not sure why. Or am I wrong?

Did I measure the margins wrongly? ( I measure the topleft and bottom right ones in [this pdf file](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/contents3.pdf)).

My `pdfcrop` is `PDFCROP 1.20, 2009/10/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2009 by Heiko Oberdiek`.

```
$ pdfinfo tmp.pdf 
Creator:        Preview
Producer:       Mac OS X 10.7.5 Quartz PDFContext
CreationDate:   Wed Sep 18 07:45:10 2013
ModDate:        Wed Sep 18 07:45:10 2013
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          6
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      85737 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3

$ pdfinfo tmpo3.pdf 
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.10
CreationDate:   Sat Nov 29 08:49:30 2014
ModDate:        Sat Nov 29 08:49:30 2014
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          6
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      471 x 670 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      251449 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

`pdfcrop` first removes the whitespace and then adds the margin (or removes space, if the values are negative). This makes it very hard to control the exact amount of space being cropped. You are better off using [`pdfcrop.sh`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42236/pdfcrop-generates-larger-file/42259#42259) which allows you to specify how much is trimmed from the outer edges of the page.